# Python overwrites the elements in the list when appending in a for loop

Tags: python

I have a for loop defined as follows;

```
formatted_atgsites=[]
a = AtgSiteToPoll()
if atgsites !=[] :
    for atgs in atgsites:

        a.SiteId = atgs.siteid
        a.IPAddress = atgs.ipaddress
        a.Port = atgs.port
        a.Category = atgs.category          
        formatted_atgsites.append(jsonEncoder.default(a))          
    return formatted_atgsites
```

The returned `formatted_atgsites` list contains the repetitive last element of the for loop. What Im doing wrong here?

Comment: can you share `print(atgsites)`

Comment: My psychic powers tell me you are appending the *same* object to the list repeatedly.  You probably want to move `a = AtgSiteToPoll()` into the loop.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks that sorted my issue